# Data is not inserting in sqli_database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

Data is not insertimg in sqli_database with php file
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h6w7.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images, edit your question and paste the code (as text)

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You Not inserted the job value in your query,
so the columns do not match the values

```
    $qry="insert into staff_record(name,phone,email,joininigdate,job,status,salary,balance) values('$name','$phone','$email','$joiningdate','$job','$status','$salary','$salary')";

/// Add  value for job  as I gave the sample '$job'
```